# Parsing JSON Swift 3 CTA Train Tracker

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am trying to parse JSON for CTA train arrivals.

```
{
ctatt =     {
    errCd = 0;
    errNm = "<null>";
    eta =         (
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:22:32";
            destNm = Howard;
            destSt = 30173;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 305;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.91065";
            lon = "-87.64918";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:32";
            rn = 843;
            rt = Red;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Howard";
            stpId = 30255;
            trDr = 1;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:21:45";
            destNm = "95th/Dan Ryan";
            destSt = 30089;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 91;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.95377";
            lon = "-87.65493";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:17:45";
            rn = 836;
            rt = Red;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward 95th/Dan Ryan";
            stpId = 30256;
            trDr = 5;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:27:28";
            destNm = Kimball;
            destSt = 30249;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 357;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.90563";
            lon = "-87.63712";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:28";
            rn = 426;
            rt = Brn;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Kimball or Linden";
            stpId = 30257;
            trDr = 1;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:27:16";
            destNm = Loop;
            destSt = 30249;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 89;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.96641";
            lon = "-87.67864";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:16";
            rn = 427;
            rt = Brn;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Loop";
            stpId = 30258;
            trDr = 5;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:28:25";
            destNm = "95th/Dan Ryan";
            destSt = 30089;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 178;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.97345";
            lon = "-87.65853";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:25";
            rn = 939;
            rt = Red;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward 95th/Dan Ryan";
            stpId = 30256;
            trDr = 5;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:32:01";
            destNm = Howard;
            destSt = 30173;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 357;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "41.87815";
            lon = "-87.6276";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:01";
            rn = 928;
            rt = Red;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Howard";
            stpId = 30255;
            trDr = 1;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:37:32";
            destNm = "95th/Dan Ryan";
            destSt = 30089;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = 162;
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 0;
            lat = "42.00566";
            lon = "-87.66565";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:32";
            rn = 926;
            rt = Red;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward 95th/Dan Ryan";
            stpId = 30256;
            trDr = 5;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:40:41";
            destNm = Kimball;
            destSt = 0;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = "<null>";
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 1;
            lat = "<null>";
            lon = "<null>";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:41";
            rn = 431;
            rt = Brn;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Kimball or Linden";
            stpId = 30257;
            trDr = 1;
        },
                    {
            arrT = "2017-05-15T23:40:41";
            destNm = "See train";
            destSt = 0;
            flags = "<null>";
            heading = "<null>";
            isApp = 0;
            isDly = 0;
            isFlt = 0;
            isSch = 1;
            lat = "<null>";
            lon = "<null>";
            prdt = "2017-05-15T23:18:41";
            rn = 434;
            rt = Brn;
            staId = 41320;
            staNm = Belmont;
            stpDe = "Service toward Loop";
            stpId = 30258;
            trDr = 5;
        }
    );
    tmst = "2017-05-15T23:18:54";
};
}
```

In my `ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=individualkeygoeshere&mapid=41320&outputType=JSON")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data
            {
                do {
                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let ctattimetable = myJSON["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [Any] {
                            print(estArrivalTime)
                            if let stationName = estArrivalTime["staNm"] {
                                print(stationName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I don't have a particular goal yet, just trying to get my head around parsing `JSON` in `Swift 3`. So what I am trying to do in this case is get the station name (staNm in the JSON) for each eta, so basically I am looking to get Belmont as the response. I get the swift compiler error Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String'. I am stuck on how to get the values for each key from eta. Anybody have any idea how I would do this? The docs for the CTA train tracker API are here: http://www.transitchicago.com/developers/ttdocs/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks everyone! All these answers helped, wish I could pick all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eta` is Array of `Dictionary` and array cannot be `subscript` with `String` type you can subscript array with `Int`, if you want to access specific key from it you need to simply loop through the array also instead of specifying eta as array of `Any` you need to specify it as array of dictionary.

```
do {
    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]

    if let ctattimetable = myJSON["ctatt"] as? [String:Any] {
        if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]] {
             for item in estArrivalTime {
                 if let stationName = item["staNm"] as? String {
                     print(stationName)
                 }
                 //You can access other keys here on item dictionary same way like staNm
             }
         }
     }
}
catch {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The JSON is a dictionary rather than *Anything*

  ```
  let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
  ```
- The value for key `eta` is an array of dictionaries rather than an array of *Anything*

  ```
  if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String:Any]]
  ```
- And if you want more than just print the value for key `staNm` you need to cast is to `String`.

Be more type specific then the compiler won't complain.

As always, don't use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. It has absolutely no effect.

Please read the comprehensive Apple article in the Swift Blog: [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Answer (score 0):

```
if let ctattimetable = myJSON["ctatt"] as? [String : Any] {
            if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                for eta in estArrivalTime {
                    if let stationName = eta["staNm"] {
                        print(stationName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in this statement

```
if let stationName = estArrivalTime["staNm"]
```

because you are getting an array of objects from this if let statement

```
if let estArrivalTime = ctattimetable["eta"] as? [Any]
```

So your have to iterate every item in this array to get `staNm` by using this loop

```
for item in estArrivalTime {
                 if let _staNm = item["staNm"] as? String {
                     print("staNm : \(_staNm)")
                 }

             }
```